# Feasibility of adding drivers to linux kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, ubuntu, linux-development

I have question regarding Linux kernel , as far as I understand, to make Linux compatible  with different machines and hardware , different device driver is added to the Linux .
I want to ask how much feasible is to add tons of device driver to Linux kernel , suppose after 30 -40 years the size of Linux kernel will be around ~1 GB . I am not able to accept and understand this philosophy of Linux .
if you say that i can edit/remove unwanted modules from Linux kernel , my answer would be that not everyone is technological sound to do so .

Comment: "my answer would be that not everyone is technological sound to do so " Every single person using Linux on the desktop loads a bunch of modules _every single time_ they boot - why do you say people can't do this?

Comment: @PhilipKendall i am saying with my experience my siblings,friends,parents and teacher they are able to use some flavour of linux for basic browsing thats all they do not care the size of operating system . but i do care i cant accept that there is a driver in my system which i will never use in my entire file . its useless space eating thing.

Comment: "i cant accept that there is a driver in my system which i will never use in my entire file " you would not BELIEVE the amount of unused junk Windows is carrying around with it.

Comment: If you really care, build yourself a custom kernel image which contains only the drivers you need. I have better things to do with my life than save myself a few Mb of storage.

Comment: @PhilipKendall firstly its a design implementation question and I am not asking you build it for me secondly i will answer this question ...wait

Comment: @pjc50 yep windows linux same issue but windows is close source i cant expect anything from windows

Comment: Why do you "suppose" what the size of the Linux kernel will be after 30 years? You can just look: Linux is 29.5 years old right now, it should be easy enough to extrapolate what the size is going to be on September, 17th 2021 when Linux becomes 30 years old. I *highly* doubt it is going to be 10 GiBytes. Last I checked, a *full* Linux system, i.e. not just the kernel but also libc, shell, utilities, etc. still fit on a single 1.44MB floppy disk.

Comment: @JörgWMittag I am inexperienced to linux internals i just wanted to point out that there are so many irrelevant driver that takes space and have no use and I think its a flaw . the correct way should be that only those driver should come along kernel image that are important, for other driver there should be a tool which can detect hardware and install them . everytime a new hardware is plug into system its driver should be installed from net/some package manager . Coming back to 10GB, i mean to say size will increase over the period of time someday it  will become a headache .

Comment: @user143252 you can't download new packages without a network driver. So the bare minimum is to include all the possible network and wifi cards. Oh, and you need all the disk, disk controller, and cdrom drivers in order to start up and to have somewhere to download them to. And so on...

Comment: @pjc50 what everyone is telling is that storage is cheap , drivers does not cost anything as long as they are not loaded in ram , linux has only those drivers which are relevant and lastly if i dont want something delete it ...my question make more sense when its asked in 1980s where Storage was costly and bulky ...

Comment: @JörgWMittag I think a Linux distro on a floppy disk is a bit of a straw man in this case. That can fit precisely because it _doesn't_ include most of the drivers which would be needed for a full system.

Comment: @user143252 The system you are advocating, which downloads drivers when they are needed, already exists. Just because someone has written a Linux driver for some obscure piece of hardware, doesn't mean that driver is immediately installed on every single computer running Linux. As for the 1980s, Linux was first released in 1991, as a one-person project supporting a very small amount of hardware; the proliferation of drivers has gone hand in hand with both cheap storage and widely available internet access, so the constraints of 40 years ago really aren't relevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have question regarding Linux kernel, as far as I understand, to make Linux compatible with different machines and hardware, different device driver is added to the Linux

That is correct, but the exact same situation is also true for other operating systems, like MS Windows.

There are several forces at play that keep the kernel to a manageable size, without requiring a deep technological knowledge from the end-users.

- People don't write a separate device driver for each individual model of some hardware.  Device drivers are written for whole families or classes of devices. This is true in both the Linux and Windows worlds, because the device manufacturers don't want to wait with selling their newest products until the software people have caught up.
- Kernel development is a moving target and that means that device drivers need to be updated from time to time. If nobody is using a particular kind of hardware anymore, then there is little interest in keeping the device drivers up-to-date and support for those devices will be dropped (which means the device drivers will also be removed).
- The Linux distributions also make choices which device drivers they install by default and which drivers are installed on-demand when the user indicates they need them.

As you can see, it is not just adding device drivers, but also removing them. And nearly all of that work gets done by knowledgeable developers, precisely because not all users have the technological know-how.

Answer (score 4):

This is not a "philosophy of Linux", it's a fact of life: over time, new hardware is invented, and needs new software to interface with it. This is true of every OS, in proportion to the range of hardware the OS supports - so, Windows will have a very similar range to Linux; MacOS much narrower due to Apple's control of the hardware platform.

How much of that software is installed by default can vary:

- some of it can be downloaded from the internet when needed, but you need a certain amount to even get that far
- some eventually becomes rare and obsolete, so will be deleted or moved into a harder to obtain archive; that inconveniences those people that do need it, but saves a bit of space for everyone else
- the manufacturer of a particular system could hand-tune the drivers installed to match the hardware included; I'm sure Android phones don't ship with unused drivers, because there is no chance of the hardware changing

In the end, it's mostly just not a problem. Storage is cheap, compared to the size of the files we're talking about. Having unused drivers on your SSD won't slow anything down, and will cost you next to nothing. If the drivers are actually loaded into RAM, that could cause performance problems, but every modern OS has a modular design that only loads the drivers actually needed.